# How to specify projection in print composer instead of in project properties for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer

I am using two map objects in QGIS print composer. One of them should be in WGS 84, being an overview of North America. The other should be in MTM 5 (close-up of a region). I can specify the projection in project properties but that sets the projections for both map objects.  Is it possible to set the projection for the map object itself?  (using QGIS 2.18 but could switch to 3.0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to my knowledge if using QGIS 2.18. You need at least 3.0 to do it.

The solution illustrated below

[image]

There is an article about this from @underdark e.g https://anitagraser.com/2018/01/20/freedom-of-projection-in-qgis3/

Comment: Got it. That will be my motivation to make the switch.

Comment: ThomasG77 Could I ask you how did you do that gif ? Did you have problems at posting because of the 2mb limit of images ?

Comment: No, never until now. More or less my tools https://labs.webgeodatavore.com/partage/short-presentation-how-to-gif-for-geospatial-illustrations.pdf + https://ezgif.com (various tools to crop screen size, remove sequence, optimize compression) to do some trade off between GIF quality and size